# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__' Anaconda

Tags: python, module, attributes, elementtree, anaconda

Good Morning,

I am using Jupyter notebooks, with Python 3.4. The error below references the Anaconda distribution package. This error occurred quite precipitously (only 2 minutes before I was able to import the modules). I am using Windows 7. My path in the console uses Python27. I also have python 34 as well. I am not sure where to start modifying the path and fear that I will break my initial setup. I welcome feedback on next steps.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\wynsa2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4ddfad7c033a> in <module>()
      6 import itertools
      7 from csv import reader
----> 8 import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree
      9 from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser
     10 

ImportError: No module named 'xml.etree'; 'xml' is not a package
```

Comment: Are the PYTHONHOME or PYTHONPATH environment variables set? If so, try unsetting them.

Comment: @asmeurer My PYTHONPATH is set to C:\Program Files\Objectivity\11.2\bin What should I change it to?

Comment: You should completely unset it.

Comment: @asmeurer - that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apparently don't have 50 reputation to add a comment. So, you want to unset the mentioned variables, which can be done with

```
set PYTHONHOME=
set PYTHONPATH=
```

This is only for the currently running shell. If you want to remove them permanently, I think the easiest way is to go to the System control panel, Advanced tab, then the click Environment Variables button. Remove the variables from the dialog that appears. You might need to log out and back in, or restart depending on the effect the variable has and when it is used.